# Outlook JS Add-in: EWS Calls using Ajax and Callback Token

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin

The Office JS API has a 1 Mb limit on callbacks, and one of the requirements I have is to forward an existing email, designated as spam by the user, as an attachment to a 3rd party. I have extensive code to handle mail operations, using makeEwsRequestAsync, and for this case SOAP that works fine to return the MIME content to create and send the email, but not when the callback return is larger than 1 Mb.

To get around the 1 Mb limitation, it was suggested to others to make the EWS call directly, using a callback token, an item Id, and the EWS URL. I can easily get these components, and I have SOAP that works for the usual makeEwsRequestAsync method.

What I don't have is how to make the call to EWS call with the elements I have.

As an example, I used the following to get the EWS URL and item Id:

```
    _mailbox = Office.context.mailbox;
    _ewsUrl = _mailbox.ewsUrl;

    var item = _mailbox.item;
    _itemId = item.itemId;
```

I use this to get the callback token:

```
    mailViaEws.Authenticate = function Start() {
        getCallbackToken(setCallbackToken);
    };

    function getCallbackToken(callback) {
        var options = {
            isRest: false
        };
        Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(options, callback);
    }

    function setCallbackToken(asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === "succeeded") {
            _callbackToken = asyncResult.value;
        } else {
            app.showNotification(_appName, asyncResult.error.message);
        }
    }
```

The SOAP is as follows, with a helper method to wrap the SOAP:

```
        var soapToCreateItem =
            '<soap:Body>' +
            '   <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy"' +
            '       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" ' +
            '       xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">' +
            '       <m:Items>' +
            '        <t:Message>' +
            '           <t:Subject>' + _subject + '</t:Subject>' +
            '           <t:Body BodyType="Text">' + _bodyText + '</t:Body>' +
            '           <t:ToRecipients>' + _adddressesSoap + '</t:ToRecipients>' +
            '        </t:Message>' +
            '       </m:Items>' +
            '    </m:CreateItem>' +
            '  </soap:Body>';

        var soapToCreateItemData = getSoapBoadyEnvelope(soapToCreateItem);
```

I've search extensively, and although I've found code that use an intermediate service to call the EWS Managed API in C#, I am trying to make the call directly to EWS. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hi, have you managed to solve the issue? I have exactly same needs :(

Comment: At the time, the company I was with had not integrated with MS Azure / O365, so it was not an option to use Graph API, but I eventually did write one that does work against Graph.

Comment: but did you manage to send a soap request to ewsurl and get back email as base64 eml?

Answer (score 0):

Your Mailbox (`_mailbox = Office.context.mailbox;`) object has a method `makeEwsRequestAsync` that you can use to make SOAP call to the EWS.
Note, that you don't need to provide access token explicitly.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services) is more information.

Comment: I already that have that done, but that method will fail when the return is greater than 1 MB. I have an extensive library - mentioned in my post - here: https://gist.github.com/JamesIgoe/05e53af69ef5eabfc3fa38d176f19925.

Comment: Could you provide a documentation related to this limitation?

Comment: Two places: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/limits-for-activation-and-javascript-api-for-outlook-add-ins#limits-for-javascript-api, along with direct conversations with MS support. Limitation is both downstream and upstream.

Comment: Generally, the approach you've choosen to solve the problem somehow odd for me. The problem can be easily solved by exchange rules. Anyway, using your approach you will traffic overhead on you client because of downloading whole spam messages and sending it. You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48015301/how-to-forward-an-email-using-office-js-add-in-api) as a solution.

Comment: I understand the limitation, and that it is more efficient to not download the MIME content, and work directly, but obviously, that is what I am trying to do. Your suggestion uses the Graph API, which is not an option, as my employer has on prem Exchange.

Comment: If thee is a better way, "easily solved by Exchange rules", please provide an example. I've tried to find other ways of generating SOAP to do the work via the Office JS API, but have not found nor seen a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Callback token you get from getCallbackTokenAsync is only good for 5 minutes and is only good for the GetAttachment and GetItem EWS operations this is documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox so your CreateItem request won't work in this context. Does the message need to come from the user if it just SPAM reporting? it would be easy just to do the send part using a Service Account with EWS or even just send it via SMTP.

Comment: This is interesting, particularly the SMTP option, I can research it, but do you have a link to an example you think particularly good? Also,while researching this, I also came across options to create my own service to work with the manged API, but to do it in C#, but this seems a bit much for an edge case. I also have not researched the REST API as much I would like.

Comment: in your intermediate you just need to either add the SMTP or EWS code to send the message, and it depends where your code is running and the permissions it has from the app pool etc or credentials you put in. For SMTP Mimekit should work also CDOSys can be used if you have an older O/S